# Disable form element after the data is saved

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a website on which the user has to enter quite a number of data using text boxes. I want to lock the textbox after the first use. I mean for the example the user has to enter his name and save it but once saved, the user should not be able to change it again.

So can anybody suggest me what changes has to be made in this code

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
    <input class="tooltip v_empty" title="first name" type="text"
    name="<?php echo "LP".$lp_id."_";  ?>firstname[self]"
    id="firstname[self]"
    value="<?php echo $PLAN->lp[$lp->lp_id]->info['self']->firstname; ?>" />
</td>
```

Comment: check if the user has the name and phone number from DB and make the text box html read only if so.

Comment: You should elaborate on what `$PLAN->lp` and the localized object setup means.

Comment: As others have said just use disabled element combined with some PHP validation on form submit (to check valid entry has been / already been sent). On another note your form value's seem to be very complicated, are you sure you need to store an array of objects within an object? Lastly I assume you have a good reason to lock the form, but fair warning you WILL have a lot of uncompleted forms / redundant data, if someone makes a spelling mistake why not give them an opportunity to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a better title. the disabled attribute in html may help you.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/deform3.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` HTML elements take a `disabled="disabled"` argument which renders the user unable to normally modify the contents of the field (it will be *greyed out*). (Take note, that local HTML source modification can result in changing the data!)

Apart from that, you should take a look at how [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) work. You should store the already entered value in a session, or the database backend, and when the form is getting printed, you should check against what value is already present in the session or database.

Comment: Ya but the initial value as to entered by the user so i cannt disabled arguement. So suggest me that some code that can lock the text box after the user enter the some data for the 1st time and he should not be able to change that.

Comment: `if ( $user_has_already_entered ) { disable_input(); } else { dont_disbale_input(); }` You first check against the database whether the user has already entered or not, and if he did, you lock the input, if he didn't, you don't lock it. It is the basicest [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) control structure.

Comment: What do you mean by _my original_? If you mean your question: the question only contains a bare example of one row, with no logic described behind the object setup. I don't know how your database is set up, nor the already existing programming logic. You are the one who needs to write and **understand** the code he wrote, we can only give suggestions about what the right track would be. The source code is on your computer, not on mine. My hands are constrained. Also, the code I gave in the above comment is a **pseudocode** to make you realize what to do. There is no sense in copypasting it.